# Is there a unique projection map in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $A,B$ be closed subspaces of $X$ such that $X=A\oplus B$. Assume that $||a+b||=||a||+||b||$ for each $(a,b)\in A\times B$.

Then, does there exist a **unique** projection $T$ on $X$ such that $im(T)=A$?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: It is obviously true when it is more assumed that$ker(T)=B$. However, if this is not assumed, I did not know what weird things would happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually not. Just consider $\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$; we have lots of projections onto the first component: anything of the form $(x,y) \mapsto (x + cy, 0)$, for $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It is off the topic, but here is what I'm curious about. The situation given above (i.e. $||a+b||=||a||+||b||$ for $(a,b)\in A\times B$) looks quite similar to the case of direct sum of a closed subspace and its orthogonal complement in **Hilbert spaces**. What properties would this yield in the case of Banach space?